# inline field are merged when adjusting label

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to create a responsive form using flex where the first name and last name will be in same column in large devices and be in separate column in small devices. I designed the form and it was working as expected(not the responsive part though)until I adjust the label in the input box. I used the `position: absolute` to adjust the label, so it break the design of first name and last name field. They got merge now.

Here is the demo

http://jsbin.com/pecijupicu/3/edit?html,css

Meanwhile, here is the source code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background: #f2f3f78a;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

aside.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #f0efef;
  margin: 0 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.form-container h3 {
  color: rgb(67, 77, 90);
}

form {
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form .field {
  margin: 15px 0;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.form-input {
  flex: 1;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}

form .field label {
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: rgb(67, 77, 90);
}

button.next {
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgb(0, 213, 229);
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button.next:after {
  content: "Next";
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  padding: 8px;
  border: transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(0, 213, 229);
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<aside class="form-container">
  <h3>Personal</h3>
  <form>
    <div class="field">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>City</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- show button to the bottom right corner -->
    <button class="next"></button>
  </form>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to the html structure and added some extra styles to suit your use case. My solution supports responsiveness as well.

link to working example: [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/cisorik/edit?html,css,output)

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  background: #f2f3f78a;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


aside.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #f0efef;
  margin: 0 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.form-container h3{
   color: rgb(67, 77, 90);
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form .field {
    margin: 15px 0;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

form .combined{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
 
}

.form-input {
  flex: 1;
}

form .combined .field{
  flex:1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

form .combined .field .form-input{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}


form .field label {
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: rgb(67, 77, 90);
}

button.next {
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgb(0,213,229);
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button.next:after {
    content: "Next";
    color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"], textarea {
    padding: 8px;
    border: transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(0,213,229);
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    form .combined{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    form .combined .field{
      flex:1;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    form .combined .field label{
      position: absolute;
      top: -11px;
    } 
    form .combined .field .form-input{
      margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<aside class="form-container">
  <h3>Personal</h3>
  <form>
    <div class="combined">
        <div class="field">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
       </div>
     </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>City</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- show button to the bottom right corner -->
    <button class="next"></button>
  </form>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Add `left: 50%` to the *lastname* `label` - it makes sense as the *absolutely positioned* labels share the full-width 50-50 due `flex: 1` given to them. See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background: #f2f3f78a;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

aside.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #f0efef;
  margin: 0 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.form-container h3 {
  color: rgb(67, 77, 90);
}

form {
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form .field {
  margin: 15px 0;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.form-input {
  flex: 1;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}

form .field label {
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: rgb(67, 77, 90);
}

form .field label:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 50%; /* ADDED */
}

button.next {
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgb(0, 213, 229);
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button.next:after {
  content: "Next";
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  padding: 8px;
  border: transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(0, 213, 229);
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<aside class="form-container">
  <h3>Personal</h3>
  <form>
    <div class="field">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>City</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- show button to the bottom right corner -->
    <button class="next"></button>
  </form>
</aside>
```

Comment: its now shown side by side but the input line is still touched. I think providing margin to `.field input:nth-of-type(2)` will work.